# How to instantiate local notifications on Isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-notifications, uilocalnotification, dart-isolates

**Background of my problem:** I am developing a Flutter app that performs a repeated background activity every few hours and notifies the user if there are any updates.

Currently, I have created an isolate function that is able to perform the background activity (but is not currently scheduled) and I'm using the flutter_local_notifications package to generate the notifications locally.

**Here's the code I have:**

*The piece that calls the isolate function-*

```
Future<void> executeBgUpdate() async {
  Completer c = Completer();

  ProductManager.close();
  Hive.close();
  Future f = compute(_isolateUpdateFunction, SharedVariables.appDocsDirPath); // See next block for code

  f.then((value) async {
    await init.db();
    c.complete(value);
  });

  return c.future;
}
```

*The isolate function-*

```
Future<void> _isolateUpdateFunction(String appDataDirPath) async {
  Completer c = Completer();

  try {
    await init.logger();
    await init.db(appDocsDirPath: appDataDirPath);
    Notifier.init(); // See next block for code

    // Background Task goes here

    await Future.wait(futures);

    Notifier.showNotification();

    ProductManager.close();
    Hive.close();
  } catch (ex, stacktrace) {
    SharedInstances.logger.e("Failed in BG Update Isolate!", ex, stacktrace);
  }

  c.complete(null);
  return c.future;
}
```

*Contents of Notifier.init()-*

```
static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notifier;

  static void init() {
    _notifier = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: null);

    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);

    _notifier.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: null);
  }
```

*The exception that I'm getting is:*

```
E/flutter (30954): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
E/flutter (30954): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
E/flutter (30954): If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.
E/flutter (30954): #0      defaultBinaryMessenger.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:73:7)
E/flutter (30954): #1      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:86:4)
E/flutter (30954): #2      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140:62)
E/flutter (30954): #3      MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:368:5)
E/flutter (30954): #4      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications.dart:94:14)
E/flutter (30954): <asynchronous suspension>
```

*If I add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() to before the Notifier is initialized in the isolate, I get this exception-*

```
error: native function 'Window_setNeedsReportTimings' (2 arguments) cannot be found

// StackTrace:
I/flutter (  433): │ #0      Window.onReportTimings= (dart:ui/window.dart:964:7)
I/flutter (  433): │ #1      SchedulerBinding.addTimingsCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:230:14)
I/flutter (  433): │ #2      SchedulerBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:206:7)
I/flutter (  433): │ #3      PaintingBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:21:11)
I/flutter (  433): │ #4      SemanticsBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/semantics/binding.dart:22:11)
I/flutter (  433): │ #5      RendererBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:29:11)
I/flutter (  433): │ #6      WidgetsBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:253:11)
I/flutter (  433): │ #7      new BindingBase (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:56:5)
I/flutter (  433): │ #8      new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #9      new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #10     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #11     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #12     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #13     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #14     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #15     new WidgetsFlutterBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (  433): │ #16     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1083:7)
```

I'm quite clueless as to how I should proceed. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: in your isolate code you should work with data only, not with anything related to UI (like notifications for example)

Comment: How do I post notifications from the background process then?

Comment: `compute` returns `Future` so send your notification when it completes

Comment: But how do I do it if the App is not running? I need to create notifications from the background..

Comment: hmmm, maybe https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager?

Comment: I did go through that package, that will allow to schedule my isolate execution. Which is what I want to do, but I still can't generate notifications if my app is closed. :(

Comment: Having the same error, but mine breaks on await getDatabasesPath. Did you figure out how to run your isolate?

Answer (score 3):

There is a package you can use called [`flutter_isolate`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate). According to its description, it allows the use of flutter plugins in a new isolate. I used it with `flutter_ffmpeg` and `sqflite` and it worked. When I tried to use them without this package I received the same error.

After adding the `flutter_isolate` package to your `pubspec.yaml`, instead of

```dart
Future f = compute(_isolateUpdateFunction, SharedVariables.appDocsDirPath);
```

You can use

```dart
Future f = FlutterIsolate.spawn(_isolateUpdateFunction, SharedVariables.appDocsDirPath);
```

The package will register all plugins automatically using the flutter generated file at `app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` (on Android. I don't know how it works on iOS). But there are some issues on github ([here](https://github.com/rmawatson/flutter_isolate/issues/13) and [here](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/169)) about plugins not working properly. So, according to the package creator, you can copy this file and create a custom plugin registrant deleting the plugins you don't need when starting a new `FlutterIsolate`. Then, in your `MainActivity` file, call the method `setCustomIsolateRegistrant` from `FlutterIsolatePlugin`.

For example:

```java
public final class IsolatePluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
    com.arthenica.flutter.ffmpeg.FlutterFFmpegPlugin
      .registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.arthenica.flutter.ffmpeg.FlutterFFmpegPlugin"));
  }
}
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FlutterIsolatePlugin.setCustomIsolateRegistrant(IsolatePluginRegistrant.class);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Have in mind I do not understand how native code works on Android. This example is inspired from an answer from one of the issues I mentioned. So, I'm not sure if this example works or even if it is correct, but this is the principle and I think it is a useful information. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man. I ended up changing the architecture to have the work done on a backend server and then sent over to the phone as a notification.